# Use Regex in two different cases

Tags: python, regex, expression, regex-lookarounds

I am trying with Python 3.7 to recognize patterns in pdf documents by extracting the elements with regular expressions. I have two casuistics when I extract the data:

The first is that the result comes to me as follows:

```
R.U.T .: 99.999.999-9
COMPANY
ELECTRONIC TICKET
Committed to you
N
54280631
COMPANY S.A. SALE
RUT: 99.999.999-9 Directory 111, City
```

And the second case is:

```
R.U.T .: 99.999.999-9
COMPANY
ELECTRONIC TICKET
Committed to you
N 54280631
COMPANY S.A. SALE
RUT: 99.999.999-9 Directory 111, City
```

I need a regular expression that can get both cases to get the invoice number with RegeX. In this case the invoice number is "N 54280631".

I have tried the following regex however it does not work for one of the two cases.

```
([N]).*\n+([0-9])+.*\w+
```

Any idea what the regex should look like to have that result?

Comment: You can use `(?m)^N\s+(\d+)$`

Comment: Please confirm the match occurs either on a whole single line or two full adjacent lines.

Comment: It's works! Thanks for all! `(?m)` is multi line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?m)^N\s+(\d+)$
```

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - an inline `re.M` modifier that makes `^` and `$` match start/end of line positions
- `^` - start of a line
- `N` - `N` char
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)`  - Group 1: one or more digits
- `$` - end of line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3SuctN/1).

In Python, you can use either `re.findall` to get all match occurrences, or `re.search` to get the first match only:

```py
import re
text = 'Your_text_here'
pattern = r'^N\s+(\d+)$'
# First match:
m = re.search(pattern, text, re.M)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))

# Get all occurrences:
print( re.findall(pattern, text, re.M) )
```